# Calculate input value in splitting - PHP

Tags: php

Here in Brazil, we can buy and split the payment.

If the total purchase was US$ 100, we can pay $ 30 at the time of purchase and divide the rest into equal amounts for the next few months.

***Example:***
US$ 30 is payable at time of purchase.
US$ 35 pay in 2018-10-04
US$ 35 pay in 2018-11-04

Based on the function below, how can I consider and calculate the value of the `$value_entry` funding entry, so that the rest is equally divided into the other installments?

I need to split a debt, but report a payment receipt.

```
function calculo_negociacao($amount, $plots, $date, $value_entry) {  
       $split = [];
       $value = $amount / $plots;
       $value = number_format((float)$value, 2, '.', '');

       $split = array_fill(0, $plots, ['value ' => $value ]);

       $date = explode( '-', $date);
       $day = $date[0];
       $month = $date[1];
       $year = $date[2];

       for($x = 0; $x < $plots; $x++){
           $split[$x]['portion'] = $x + 1; 
           $split[$x]['date'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+".$x." month",mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year)));
       }       
       return $split;
}
$value = 150.07;
$value_entry= 50.00;
$portion = 4;
$date = '04-09-2018';
$negotiation = calculo_negociacao($value, $portion, $date, $value_entry);
var_dump($negotiation);
echo json_encode($negotiation);
```

Comment: There is a lot going on in this function, could you give us a better description of what you're trying to do? What this formula does?

Comment: What are you expecting? Can you show input and output? And I would advise you to write variables in English, at least when you post code here on SO.

Comment: Ok, variables are in Portuguese, Brazilian, I will write.

Comment: Hello @Andreas, variables renamed!

I need to split a debit but report a pay entry

Comment: Good. But your question is still unclear. You should read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: maybe the words used in america are not the same as those used in brazil. I'll try to explain better.

Comment: Treating currency as float type is going to burn you.

Comment: @symcbean, what is your suggestion ?

Comment: Use ints then recalculate any rounding errors at the end. Use string splicing to inject the decimal. Not my suggestion, standard practice.

Comment: certain, in this case I have a difference of 0.01.

I'll try it this way. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this:

```
function calculo_negociacao($amount, $plots, $date, $value_entry) {  

    $plots--; // the first will be the entry
    $split = [];

    // each plot value
    $value = ($amount - $value_entry) / $plots;
    $value = number_format((float)$value, 2, '.', '');

    // entry + number of plots
    $split = array_fill(0, $plots + 1, ['value' => $value ]);

    $date = explode( '-', $date);
    $day = $date[0];
    $month = $date[1];
    $year = $date[2];

    // position 0 will be the entry
    $split[0]['portion'] = 1;
    $split[0]['value'] = $value_entry;
    $split[0]['date'] = date("Y-m-d", mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year));

    // plots
    for($x = 0; $x < $plots; $x++){
        $split[$x + 1]['portion'] = $x + 2; 
        $split[$x + 1]['date'] = date("Y-m-d",strtotime("+". ($x+1) ." month",mktime(0, 0, 0, $month, $day, $year))); // I changed to ($x+1) here 
    }       
    return $split;
}
$value = 150.07;
$value_entry= 50.00;
$portion = 4;
$date = '04-09-2018';
$negotiation = calculo_negociacao($value, $portion, $date, $value_entry);
var_dump($negotiation);
echo json_encode($negotiation);
```

The result will be:

```
[
   {
      "value":50,
      "portion":1,
      "date":"2018-09-04"
   },
   {
      "value":"33.36",
      "portion":2,
      "date":"2018-10-04"
   },
   {
      "value":"33.36",
      "portion":3,
      "date":"2018-11-04"
   },
   {
      "value":"33.36",
      "portion":4,
      "date":"2018-12-04"
   }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but in place of input, can I keep as 1, and if it is plot two, send 2, and so on in the item "portion" of the array?

In this case, if I do not need to be displayed in the item portion, the value entry.

Let it be only 1

Comment: almost works, as I need it.

But although it is the maximum of 4 parcels, they are dividing in 5.

I believe the right would be 1 + 3 installments.

it's possible ?

Comment: works in parts, because of the form that it is, are 5 parcels and not 4.

Comment: I´ve updated before my last comment, dont you saw it?

Comment: I did not see it, but I saw it now and it's very good.

Thank you for your help